# Best way to fill a SVG shape with other elements without clipping them at boundary?

Tags: svg, overflow

I need to create several SVG shapes (like circles or polygons) and fill each one of them with some SVG elements.

One way to achieve this is to define the shape and apply a pattern with the fill attribute (cf. snippet below). However, the inner SVG elements are clipped by the outer shape's boundary (the triangles are clipped by the circle).

I would like to find a way to hide all the triangles that do not intersect with the circle, and leave the triangles that overflow at the boundary intact.

Please note that computing whether an element intersects with a circle is quite easy in Javascript but I need to create shapes with complicated boundaries such as polygons.

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern -->

<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <pattern id="Triangle" width="10" height="10"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <polygon points="5,0 10,10 0,10"/>
 </pattern>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="url(#Triangle)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is exactly what I need, I will have to study your solution to see if I can implement it for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is my sample code, but it is a bit tricky (uses pattern and mask and filter).

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!--common settings-->
  <defs>
    <!--pattern to detect shape area-->
    <pattern id="Dots" width="10" height="10"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="4" y="4" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
    </pattern>
    <!--filter to find area in which pattern shapes must be painted-->
    <filter id="Range">
      <feMorphology radius="4" operator="dilate"/>
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feConvolveMatrix order="2 2" kernelMatrix="1 1 1 1" divisor="1"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <!--paint structure-->
  <defs>
    <!--base shape-->
    <circle id="Base" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
    <!--pattern for filling-->
    <pattern id="Triangle" width="10" height="10"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <polygon points="5,0 10,10 0,10"/>
    </pattern>
    <!--mask by paint area-->
    <mask id="Mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="url(#Dots)" stroke="url(#Dots)" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#Range)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
  <!--fill all screen by pattern and mask by paint area-->
  <rect fill="url(#Triangle)" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#Mask)"/> 
</svg>
```

So I explain it step by step.

1) find "hit area"(center points of pattern shapes included by paint area of base shape) by using dot pattern filling.

`stroke-width` is used to enlarge base shape.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background-color:gray;">
  <!--common settings-->
  <defs>
    <!--pattern to detect shape area-->
    <pattern id="Dots" width="10" height="10"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="4" y="4" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <!--paint structure-->
  <defs>
    <!--base shape-->
    <circle id="Base" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
  <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="url(#Dots)" stroke="url(#Dots)" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

2) fatten the hit area by filter. This is pattern area.

`feConvolveMatrix` is used to make box size to be even.

10px(pattern unit size) = 1px(dot size) + 4 * 2px(feMorphology) + 1px(feConvolveMatrix)

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background-color:gray;">
  <!--common settings-->
  <defs>
    <!--pattern to detect shape area-->
    <pattern id="Dots" width="10" height="10"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="4" y="4" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
    </pattern>
    <!--filter to find area in which pattern shapes must be painted-->
    <filter id="Range">
      <feMorphology radius="4" operator="dilate"/>
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feConvolveMatrix order="2 2" kernelMatrix="1 1 1 1" divisor="1"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <!--paint structure-->
  <defs>
    <!--base shape-->
    <circle id="Base" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="url(#Dots)" stroke="url(#Dots)" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#Range)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#Base" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

3) finally , spread `rect` element to all svg area, and fill it by pattern shapes and mask it by pattern area created at 2).

Answer (score 2):

*This answer does not help the OP now.  But I am posting this anyway as it might help future readers.*

The following Javascript function should fill any shape with any pattern.  It uses the new SVG2 `SVGSVGElement.checkIntersection()` method.

*Unfortunately, `checkIntersection()` doesn't work properly yet in any browsers. The method call works in Chrome, but it doesn't perform the intersection test properly. The other browsers haven't even implemented the method.*

```js
function fillShapeWithPattern(shapeId, patternId)
{
  var shape = document.getElementById(shapeId);
  var pattern = document.getElementById(patternId);
  var svg = shape.ownerSVGElement;

  var shapeBounds = shape.getBBox();
  var patternBounds = pattern.getBBox();
  
  if (patternBounds.width == 0 || patternBounds.height == 0)
    return;  // Avoid infinite loops

  // To simplify the intersection test, let's adjust the shape bounding
  // boxe so that we can pretend the pattern box is at (0,0).
  shapeBounds.x -= patternBounds.x;
  shapeBounds.y -= patternBounds.y;

  // An SVGRect object that we need for the intersection test
  var testRect = svg.createSVGRect();
  testRect.width = patternBounds.width;
  testRect.height = patternBounds.height;

  // Loop through a grid checking whether a rectangle representing
  // the bounding box of the pattern, intersect with the shape
  for (var y = shapeBounds.y;
           y < (shapeBounds.y + shapeBounds.height);
           y += patternBounds.height)
  {
    testRect.y = y + patternBounds.y;

    for (var x = shapeBounds.x;
             x < (shapeBounds.x + shapeBounds.width);
             x += patternBounds.width)
    {
      testRect.x = x + patternBounds.y;

      if (svg.checkIntersection(shape, testRect))
      {
        // Add a copy of the pattern shape to the SVG, by creating
        // a <use> element at the right coordinates
        var use = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "use");
        use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#"+patternId);
        use.setAttribute("x", x);
        use.setAttribute("y", y);
        svg.appendChild(use);
      }
    }
  }
}


fillShapeWithPattern("shape", "pattern");
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <polygon id="pattern" points="5,0 10,10 0,10"/>
  </defs>

  <circle id="shape" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```